# Java display length of int containing leading zeros

Tags: java

I want to display the length of a 4-digit number displayed by the user, the problem that I'm running into is that whenever I read the length of a number that is 4-digits long but has trailing zeros the length comes to the number of digits minus the zeros.

Here is what I tried:

```
//length of values from number input
int number = 0123;
int length = (int)Math.log10(number) + 1;
```

This returns to length of 3
The other thing I tried was:

```
int number = 0123;
int length = String.valueOf(number).length();
```

This also returned a length of 3.

Are there any alternatives to how I can obtain this length?

Comment: I think you are having problems with the "leading" zeros, not trailing. Presumably the user will be prompted somehow for their input? Most likely that will be a string. A String has a length property.

Comment: A number doesn't have leading 0. A String can. What you have there is an octal integer literal (i.e. 3 + 2 * 8^1 + 1 * 8^2)

Comment: int type cannot have leading zeroes

Comment: Specifically, as an octal value, `0123 == 83.`

Comment: @DavidConrad That explains why it's returning 2 for me and not 3.

Comment: Thank you guys, I was trying to avoid turning my number into a String but this explains why int simply doesn't work. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `int number = 0123` is the equivalent of `int number = 83` as `0123` is an `octal` constant. Thanks to @DavidConrad and @DrewKennedy for the `octal` precision.

Instead declare it as a `String` if you want to keep the leading `0`

```
String number = "0123";
int length = number.length();
```

And then when you need the number, simply do `Integer.parseInt(number)`

---

**Why is the syntax of octal notation in java 0xx ?**

> Java syntax was designed to be close to that of C, see eg page 20 at
>   How The JVM Spec Came To Be keynote from the JVM Languages Summit 2008
>   by James Gosling (20_Gosling_keynote.pdf):

In turn, this is the way how octal constants are defined in C language:

> If an integer constant begins with 0x or 0X, it is hexadecimal. If it
>   begins with the digit 0, it is octal. Otherwise, it is assumed to be
>   decimal...

Note that this part is a C&P of @gnat answer on programmers.stackexchange.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/221797/reasoning-behind-the-syntax-of-octal-notation-in-java

Comment: `int number = 0123` is the equivalent of `int number = 83`; it's an octal constant.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard It doesn't. It returns 2 - tested myself. I'm surmising the OP was making an assumption it would equal 3.

Comment: Yeah, OP either didn't actually try that, or what was tried and what was reported to us were two different things.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I've learned more from StackOverflow than I have from the classroom. It happens. :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I should have stated that I wanted to avoid using a string but I see that there is no was to avoid it because of what was explained in the comments following the question. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Use a string instead:

```
String number = "0123";
int length = number.length(); // equals 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work with an int, as the internal representation of 0123 is identical to 123. The program doesn't remember how the value was written, only the actual value.

What you can do is declare a string:

```
String number = "0123";
int numberLengthWithLeadingZeroes = number.length(); // == 4
int numberValue = Integer.parseInt(number); // == 123
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to include leading 0's you could always store it in an array of of characters

example:

```
char[] abc = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();
```

Then obviously you can figure out the length of the array.

As several people have pointed out already though, integers don't have leading 0's.

Comment: Put another line after "example:" so the code is formatted. Thanks.

Comment: @mbomb007 Good call, totally missed that. Fixed now.

Comment: Why not just use a `String`?

Comment: You definitely could, some of it depends on what you would want to then do with the number. For example, I took this code snippet from a program I wrote where I had to manipulate each individual number, hence the char array.

Comment: He doesn't need mutability, so `char[]` seems excessive

Answer (score 0):

```
String abc=String.format("%04d", yournumber);
```

for zero-padding with length=4.
Refer to this link .

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

this might help u ..

Answer (score 0):

`Integer`s in Java don't have leading zeroes. If you assign the value `0123` to your `int` or `Integer` variable, it will be interpreted as an octal constant rather than a decimal one, which can lead to subtle bugs.

Instead, if you want to keep leading zeroes, use a `String`, e.g.

```
String number = "0123";
```

This way you can also measure the length:

```
String number = "0123";
System.out.println(number.length());
```